# ImageView added in RelativeView gets scaled down

Tags: android

I have added two imageviews in a relative layout and get a strange behavior. The last image scales one of the last image down to 50% when using RelativeLayout.BELOW and programaticly adding the image. One of my images is displayed below the other one. I use this code:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.setId(10001);

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    _imageView = new ImageView(getActivity());
    _imageView.setId(10002);
    _imageView.setImageResource(_resource);
    layout.addView(_imageView, params);     

    params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, _imageView.getId());
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, _imageView.getId());

    ImageView shadowImage = new ImageView(getActivity());
    shadowImage.setId(10003);
    shadowImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.card_shadow);
    shadowImage.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    layout.addView(shadowImage, params);
```

But when I use xml instead of programaticly adding the image I get the image in full size:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/cardShadow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@drawable/card_01"
    android:src="@drawable/card_shadow"
    android:contentDescription=""/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/card_01" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added:

```
shadowImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Which allows no scaling of the ImageView. Thanks by the way for some good insights and tips.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overlap your images then you should use FrameLayout

Answer (score 0):

You're using WRAP_CONTENT in Java code for both the Relative Layout params but MATCH_PARENT for it in the XML code. Guess that's the catch. :)

Comment: Got the same issue changing layoutparams. I attach it to a fragment inside a ViewPager.